# Read Input without using io.h in assembly

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, masm32

I'm using masm32 for learning programing 32bit assembly programs. I want to know how i can directly read from input (like 16-bit assembly, call interrupt or something like) without use of io.h predefined macros and procs? Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Yes. You call APIs provided by the operating system. On Windows, console I/O is done by calling functions like [`ReadConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958.aspx) and [`WriteConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401.aspx). These are provided by Windows SDK headers (`windows.h`) and associated libraries that you link into your binary. Interrupts are not used for this purpose in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want write it from scratch, is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible to write it from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using older OSes like DOS, you can call e.g. [INT 16h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H) to ask the BIOS for a keypress. Unfortunately, this is not possible under NT-like Windows. For a bunch of reasons (security and stability being the most important), access to BIOS interrupts is controlled by the Windows kernel, and is therefore restricted for regular apps.

In other words, you have to get all keystrokes through Windows kernel calls, directly or indirectly. There is no other way. You call the OS, the OS calls the kernel, the kernel calls the BIOS.

But anyway, in case you still want to use interrupts, there is a possibility — at the cost of becoming even more platform-dependent than after choosing MASM32 as the target language.

Under 32-bit Windows, many of the Windows APIs from NTDLL can be accessed via [INT 2Eh](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/the-sysenter-instruction-and-0x2e-interrupt/). The problem is that different versions of Windows (sometimes even different *builds* of the same version) differ in INT 2Eh function numbers.

Think twice whether you want such level of platform-dependence before you start researching this topic.

Comment: The APIs are *not* designed to be called that way, and it serves absolutely no useful purpose to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray it does serve a purpose. In malware, for example, it may help avoid usermode API tracing and import table analysis.

Comment: Hmm, great, just what we need, ways to write malware. I don't consider that "useful".

Comment: @CodyGray purposes are not bound to be good, so it\`s incorrect to state that INT2E serves no purpose. Furthermore, being informed about malware-related tricks does not equal using them to create malware.

Comment: You have answered what is obviously a beginner's question with something that is an obscure, advanced technique that I think we can both agree is *not recommended* for general use, and has limited relevance even outside of that. So yeah, security by obscurity is not a successful strategy, and being informed about malware tricks is certainly useful, but not for beginners, and not for general software development. Which brings me back to my original claim: I don't think your answer is useful because I think the guidance lies somewhere between suspect and actively harmful.